# Trying to find/understand correct implementation of Harris Corners

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to understand how to compute the Harris Corner M, as defined in
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/07wi/homework/hw3/

It seems that you need to sum over a bunch of patches.

However, I've seen lots of implementations that do something like this:

```
  R = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2) - k*(Ix2 + Iy2).^2;
```

from: http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~slazebni/spring14/harris.m

There is no summing and you never look at a patch.

These don't look equivalent to me. For example, the "R" value for pixel 5,5 is just Ix2, Iy2, and Ixy value squared just for that pixel. However, the math seems to suggest you sum over a patch over, say, pixel 5,5. Which implementation is correct? Both? Are they equivalent?

Note: Ix2 = squared gradient of Image I in x direction
Iy2 is the same except in y direction
Ixy = Ix.*Iy

Also, the .* or .^ is matlab notation indicating point-wise multiplication or exponentiation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For self-containment, the calculation of the Harris Corners is based on the calculation of the correlation matrix `M`:

[image]

For each pixel in the image, you want to collect a `N x N` pixel window weighted by Gaussian weights and compute the response value `R` at the location `(x,y)` in the image by:

[image]

Values of `R` that surpass a threshold are deemed to be interest points.  `Ix` and `Iy` are the horizontal and vertical derivatives respectively. Now, the code you're concerned about I'm going to put it into this post for self-containment.  BTW, this should be credited to [Peter Kovesi](http://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/) who wrote the original function as linked in your post:

```
% HARRIS - Harris corner detector
%
% Usage:  [cim, r, c] = harris(im, sigma, thresh, radius, disp)
%
% Arguments:   
%            im     - image to be processed.
%            sigma  - standard deviation of smoothing Gaussian. Typical
%                     values to use might be 1-3.
%            thresh - threshold (optional). Try a value ~1000.
%            radius - radius of region considered in non-maximal
%                     suppression (optional). Typical values to use might
%                     be 1-3.
%            disp   - optional flag (0 or 1) indicating whether you want
%                     to display corners overlayed on the original
%                     image. This can be useful for parameter tuning.
%
% Returns:
%            cim    - binary image marking corners.
%            r      - row coordinates of corner points.
%            c      - column coordinates of corner points.
%
% If thresh and radius are omitted from the argument list 'cim' is returned
% as a raw corner strength image and r and c are returned empty.

% Reference: 
% C.G. Harris and M.J. Stephens. "A combined corner and edge detector", 
% Proceedings Fourth Alvey Vision Conference, Manchester.
% pp 147-151, 1988.
%
% Author: 
% Peter Kovesi   
% Department of Computer Science & Software Engineering
% The University of Western Australia
% pk@cs.uwa.edu.au  www.cs.uwa.edu.au/~pk
%
% March 2002

function [cim, r, c] = harris(im, sigma, thresh, radius, disp)

error(nargchk(2,5,nargin));

dx = [-1 0 1; -1 0 1; -1 0 1]; % Derivative masks
dy = dx'; %'

Ix = conv2(im, dx, 'same');    % Image derivatives
Iy = conv2(im, dy, 'same');    

% Generate Gaussian filter of size 6*sigma (+/- 3sigma) and of
% minimum size 1x1.
g = fspecial('gaussian',max(1,fix(6*sigma)), sigma);

Ix2 = conv2(Ix.^2, g, 'same'); % Smoothed squared image derivatives
Iy2 = conv2(Iy.^2, g, 'same');
Ixy = conv2(Ix.*Iy, g, 'same');

cim = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2)./(Ix2 + Iy2 + eps); % Harris corner measure

% Alternate Harris corner measure used by some.  Suggested that
% k=0.04 - I find this a bit arbitrary and unsatisfactory.
%   cim = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2) - k*(Ix2 + Iy2).^2; 

if nargin > 2   % We should perform nonmaximal suppression and threshold

% Extract local maxima by performing a grey scale morphological
% dilation and then finding points in the corner strength image that
% match the dilated image and are also greater than the threshold.
sze = 2*radius+1;                   % Size of mask.
mx = ordfilt2(cim,sze^2,ones(sze)); % Grey-scale dilate.
cim = (cim==mx)&(cim>thresh);       % Find maxima.

[r,c] = find(cim);                  % Find row,col coords.

if nargin==5 & disp      % overlay corners on original image
    figure, imagesc(im), axis image, colormap(gray), hold on
    plot(c,r,'ys'), title('corners detected');
end

else  % leave cim as a corner strength image and make r and c empty.
r = []; c = [];
end
```

`cim` is the correlation matrix that is computed, or `M(x,y)` for each pixel location `(x,y)` in the image. I can see where your source of confusion is.  In this code, the windows to compute `M(x,y)` are assumed to be 1 x 1.  In the link you referenced me to, the windows are actually 5 x 5 for each point you're looking at in the code.  If you want to extend this so that the correlation matrix incorporates 5 x 5 pixels, something like this comes to mind:

```
%//.........

%// From before - Need to modify to accommodate for window size
% Generate Gaussian filter of size 5 x 5 with sigma value
g = fspecial('gaussian', 5, sigma);

Ix2 = conv2(Ix.^2, g, 'same'); % Smoothed squared image derivatives
Iy2 = conv2(Iy.^2, g, 'same');
Ixy = conv2(Ix.*Iy, g, 'same');

%// New - add this before the computation of cim
kernel = ones(5,5); 
Ix2 = conv2(Ix2, kernel, 'same'); % To incorporate 5 x 5 patches
Iy2 = conv2(Iy2, kernel, 'same');
Ixy = conv2(Ixy, kernel, 'same');

%// Continue with original code....
cim = (Ix2.*Iy2 - Ixy.^2)./(Ix2 + Iy2 + eps); % Harris corner measure

%//.....
```

[`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) performs convolution between an input and `kernel`, which is a weighted sum of local patches and the kernel.  In this case, we need to sum over each of `Ix2`, `Iy2` and `Ixy` to respect the notation in `M`.  If we specify the kernel to be all 1s in a 5 x 5 window, this is essentially adding all of the values together and outputting this sum for each location in the image.  Now, in the link it says that the kernel is **Gaussian**.  The document says you can pre-filter your images with a Gaussian and just accumulate the windows after that, and the code currently is doing that.  However, you need to make sure that the window size of the Gaussian is the same as what the document says, so we change this to 5 x 5 as well.

You can now compute `cim` or the correlation matrix `M(x,y)` as normal which should now incorporate the summation of pixels of a 5 x 5 window for `Ix2`, `Iy2` and `Ixy` using just element-wise operations.  Each element of `Ix2`, `Iy2` and `Ixy` once we change the code computes a summation of derivative values within a 5 x 5 window where each pixel in each variable marks the summation where that location served as the centre.  After this point, once you compute `cim`, this would thus give you `M(x,y)` for each pixel in `im`.

Now, the rest of the code performs what is called non-maximum suppression.  This ensures that you remove corner points that are potentially false positives. What that means is that you take a look at image patches and determine what the **maximum** value is in this patch.  If this maximum value in this patch is equal to the **centre** of this patch **and** if this maximum value surpasses a threshold, you keep this point.  This is exactly what this part of the code does:

```
sze = 2*radius+1;                   % Size of mask.
mx = ordfilt2(cim,sze^2,ones(sze)); % Grey-scale dilate.
cim = (cim==mx)&(cim>thresh);       % Find maxima.
```

[`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html) is an order-statistics filter where the first input is the image you want, the second input is the **order-statistic** you are looking for and the third input is the neighbourhood of pixels you want to process.  This is telling us that you want the **largest order-statistics** or `sze^2`, which corresponds to the **maximum** value contained in a `sze x sze = ones(sze)` neighbourhood.

The next part of the code:

```
[r,c] = find(cim);                  % Find row,col coords.

if nargin==5 & disp      % overlay corners on original image
    figure, imagesc(im), axis image, colormap(gray), hold on
    plot(c,r,'ys'), title('corners detected');
end
```

... finds the exact row and column coordinates of those points that passed non-maximum suppression and shows these points on the image if so desired.

That explains Harris Corner Detection in a nutshell... hope that helps!

Comment: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/07wi/homework/hw3/ Seems to suggest you do sum over patches. All the other notes on harris corner, seem to suggest you sum. Am I misreading the notation?

Comment: correlation matrix? Is that handled by ordfilt2?

Comment: `cim` is the correlation matrix or the `R` matrix that is computed in the URL you sent me.  `ordfilt2` is used to help suppress non-maxima.

Comment: Where does this occur: "collect patches of these values in the correlation matrix together"?

Comment: @lars - OK, I see what's going on now.  Kovesi's code doesn't consider using a 5 x 5 window.  He just uses a single pixel or 1 x 1 window.  The window that is specified as input into the function is for non-maximal suppression.

Comment: @lars - That's done in `ordfilt2` when performing NMS.  Looking at patches to perform it.  However, I see where you're going now.  What this code is doing is that the window is assumed to be 1 x 1, not 5 x 5.... so if you want to extend this code, you can add a couple of more lines that produces another matrix where each output is the summation of 5 x 5 correlation matrix values together.  I'll modify my post.

Comment: Does "That's done in ordfilt2" refer to "collect patches of these values in the correlation matrix together".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89420/discussion-between-rayryeng-and-lars).

Comment: @rayryeng Awesome explanation :D is your gold badge any closer haha?

Comment: @imaluengo Hahaha yup, :). You and Ander will be the first ones to know when I get it. Thanks for the compliments :)

Comment: But why do you have to dliate?

Comment: @ParthibanRajendran Dilating a grayscale image corresponds to finding the *maximum* within the structuring element.  Choosing a structuring element that is square simplifies to finding the maximum within that size window corresponding to the size of the square.  This is essentially performing non-maximum suppression.  Without doing this, you get a lot of false positives.  This is standard in corner detection algorithms and it's required.  Using `ordfilt2` and choosing the largest value is equivalent to dilation.  I've explained this in my post above.

Comment: thank you. can we mathematically show how dilation simplifies finding local maximum? I could see the result, but unable to visualize the mechanism.

Comment: @ParthibanRajendran It's quite clear in MathWorks documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-dilation-and-erosion.html#mw_870854ff-1cfa-4a13-94a5-58fd427d9d55.  Also, Wikipedia explains it quite nicely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)#Grayscale_dilation